# How do you properly import files in java?

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently doing a project in my first java class. This is my first semester coding java and I am a C++ main so it has been kind of difficult picking things up. The main issue I am currently having is that for whatever reason my main file won't recognize the methods that I implemented in my class file.

The main file is called Main.java and it header is as follows:

```
            package com.auda;
            import javafx.application.Application;
            import javafx.scene.Scene;
            import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
            import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
            import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
            import javafx.stage.Stage;
            import java.awt.*;
```

The header for my methods file is as follows:

```
            package com.auda
            import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.*;
```

The errors I'm getting are as follows:

symbol: class MyShape location: class Main Main.java:20: error: cannot find symbol MyShape s1 = new MyShape(1000, 700, Color.green); I got 34 of these errors, all for methods in my method file.

The entirety of my code is https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9bKR.jpg

Basically the compiler refuses to recognize the methods in my class file. Sorry if this is poorly formatted. I don't have the tenure on this platform to post pictures of my code and I don't want to post a bunch of pages of code.

Comment: Given most of your imports and the [tag:javafx] tag on this question I assume you're trying to create a JavaFX application. However, you have AWT imports (i.e. `java.awt.*`). AWT is another UI toolkit. JavaFX is not based on AWT and so there's typically no reason to use AWT classes in a JavaFX application (there are obviously exceptions). Now, there's a class `java.awt.Color` that you seem to be using but it's not compatible with JavaFX; you should use `javafx.scene.paint.Color` in JavaFX. I'm not sure this will fix all your problems, but removing referfences to AWT should help.

Answer (score 2):

Randy's answer is right, but it won't cause the error message you are getting (you'll get `MyShape is Abstract; cannot be instantiated`). Your message has occurred because the compiler can't find the MyShape class.

Your imports should work the file structure of your project is something like this:

- java/com/auda/Main.java
- java/com/auda/Shapes.java

If you have any other folders, for example if Shapes.java is in java/com/auda/shapes/Shapes.java you will run into issues. In this case, you would need to change the package for Shapes.java to com.auda.shapes and import the classes you wish to use using `import com.auda.shapes.MyShape` or `import com.auda.shapes.*`.

However, only one of the shape classes you posted was public. The other classes you have written will have default visibility and can't be used outside of their package (see https://www.baeldung.com/java-access-modifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class (MyShape) cannot be initiated directly from the main class, you should create a child class to implement the abstract class and use it to create the New Object.

Reference : https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/java-abstract-class-method/ (Rules No 2)

> Note 2: Abstract class cannot be instantiated which means you cannot
> create the object of it. To use this class, you need to create another
> class that extends this this class and provides the implementation of
> abstract methods, then you can use the object of that child class to
> call non-abstract methods of parent class as well as implemented
> methods(those that were abstract in parent but implemented in child
> class).

Comment: I have child classes. Like I have MyRectangle, MyPolygon, MyCircle. In my main code I don't use MyShape on its own.

Comment: In the Main Class in the code line number 18, it initiate MyShape directly from the class.